# Selecting table inside dynamic query within Stored Procedure returning empty rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently building a stored procedure and my issue is where I bulk insert a new table and then compare what is different to an older vision of the table (if it exists. It is based off of its unique id).

I am running a dynamic query within this stored procedure in order to pass the name of the older version of said table as a parameter. However, when I select the table, or try to select into, insert into, etc., the table is returning empty. This makes it impossible to check for rows that are gone in the new table that is imported. The old, loc.'+@tablename+' table already exists on the db, and is not dropped until the end of the stored procedure. Is there something wrong with the order I am doing this? I am at a loss. This dynamic query works in a single statement (not a SP). The only part of this query i am really struggling with is the beginning, selecting the original loc. table. When I print the script, it looks like it should run, the table name is passed correctly.

```
IF EXISTS (select distinct MerchantName from #Temp where Merchant_ID in 
(select Merchant_ID from MerchantID_Table_Reference))
begin

declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)

set @cmd = '
select * from loc.'+@tablename+'

select * into #Temp3 from loc.'+@tablename+'

select * from #Temp3


select * into #closed from 
(select Master_ID from #Temp3
except
select Master_ID from #Temp) t



select * from #closed 

if exists (select * from #closed)
begin

update #Temp3 
set ST_Status = (''Closed'')
where Master_ID in (select Master_ID from #closed)


insert into #Temp 
select * from #Temp3
where Master_ID in (select Master_ID from #closed)


end

select * from #closed

drop table #closed
drop table loc.'+@tablename+'
drop table #Temp3

'
print (@cmd)
exec(@cmd)


end
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug, honestly, but there is one test you can run. Create the #temp3 table before executing the SQL String (obviously change the SELECT .. INTO statement into an INSERT... SELECT statement), and see what your results look like.  Also, you should specify what version of SQL Server your are running.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I am running SQL Server 2014.12.1   I created the #temp3 table as you said and as I expected, it is empty. SQL believes this table is empty for some reason.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you have shown us.  The table must actually be empty at the time you are querying it.

Comment: A couple of other questions: 1) Why do you run `drop table loc.'+@tablename+'
` in the dynamic query? Are you creating it on the fly also?  2) I assume that your first `select * from #Temp3` statement returns no rows - is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is being created on the fly also. And that select * from #temp3 statement also returned no rows. However I resolved the issue by simply creating and inserting into the temp3 table in a previous command. Not sure why that works but it does